# t-sql Using dense_rank to group records with where condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Actual data:

```
division    ID          order       date     
ABC123      ZZZ123      ORDERT1     1/17/2013       
ABC123      ZZZ123      1111112     1/25/2013       
ABC123      ZZZ123      ORDERT2     2/22/2013       
ABC123      ZZZ123      1234567     2/26/2013       
ABC123      YYY222      ORDERT2     3/20/2013       
XYZ456      ZZZ123      5555555     2/09/2012       
XYZ456      ZZZ123      ORDERT2     4/13/2012       
XYZ456      ZZZ123      5555777     6/23/2012       
XYZ456      ZZZ123      ORDERT2     10/5/2012       
XYZ456      ZZZ123      8888899     11/18/2012
```

For given data, when the order is like `'ORDER%'` a new `ORDER_group` should be started.  Each should be grouped by `division, ID` and sorted by `date`.

I was thinking I could do a `DENSE_RANK` partitioning by `division, ID`, but I need to "change" the `group` when the order is like `'ORDER%'`

Expected results:

```
division    ID          order       date        ORDER_group
ABC123      ZZZ123      ORDERT1     1/17/2013   1    
ABC123      ZZZ123      1111112     1/25/2013   1   
ABC123      ZZZ123      ORDERT2     2/22/2013   2    
ABC123      ZZZ123      1234567     2/26/2013   2    
ABC123      YYY222      ORDERT2     3/20/2013   1    
XYZ456      ZZZ123      5555555     2/09/2012   1    
XYZ456      ZZZ123      ORDERT2     4/13/2012   2    
XYZ456      ZZZ123      5555777     6/23/2012   2    
XYZ456      ZZZ123      ORDERT2     10/5/2012   3    
XYZ456      ZZZ123      8888899     11/18/2012  3
```

Note that when `division` or `ID` change, so should the `ORDER_group`.  It should be assumed that all records will have an order_group of 1.  Once a given record encounters an order with value like 'ORDER%', it should increment the order_group for a given division/ID; all sorted by date to keep things in order.

Hopefully I've fully illustrated exactly what I'm trying to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why is this record with "Order_Group" as "1"? "ABC123      YYY222      ORDERT2     3/20/2013   1". This should be "Order_Group" as "3" I think.

Comment: Is the row order enforced? Because otherwise how do you know that 1111112 belongs to ORDERT1?

But I think you can do some case logic and then partition your rank over that case to solve your issue.

Comment: The division/ID combination of ABC123/ZZZ123 changed to ABC123/YYY222, so the order_group should "reset" back to zero.  I corrected a date error in the sample data that may have also been confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think it is possible using `DENSE_RANK`. This is because there is no way of knowing that `1111112` belongs to `ORDERT1` hence how sql is going to `GROUP BY`.

I was able to do this using loops. Also I assume that the data currently present in the table is already ordered by `division` and `id`, the way it is shown in the table.

Also, not sure how it is going to be performance wise.

```
DECLARE @MainTable TABLE
(
    division VARCHAR(10),
    Id VARCHAR(10),
    [order] VARCHAR(10),
    [date] DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @MainTable VALUES('ABC123','ZZZ123','ORDERT1','1/17/2013')
INSERT INTO @MainTable VALUES('ABC123','ZZZ123','1111112','1/25/2013')
INSERT INTO @MainTable VALUES('ABC123','ZZZ123','ORDERT2','2/22/2013')
INSERT INTO @MainTable VALUES('ABC123','ZZZ123','1234567','1/22/2013')
INSERT INTO @MainTable VALUES('ABC123','YYY222','ORDERT2','3/20/2013')
INSERT INTO @MainTable VALUES('XYZ456','ZZZ123','5555555','2/09/2012')
INSERT INTO @MainTable VALUES('XYZ456','ZZZ123','ORDERT2','4/13/2012')
INSERT INTO @MainTable VALUES('XYZ456','ZZZ123','5555777','6/23/2012')
INSERT INTO @MainTable VALUES('XYZ456','ZZZ123','ORDERT2','10/5/2012')
INSERT INTO @MainTable VALUES('XYZ456','ZZZ123','8888899','11/18/2012')

DECLARE @RequiredTable TABLE
(
    RowId INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    division VARCHAR(10),
    Id VARCHAR(10),
    [order] VARCHAR(10),
    [date] DATETIME,
    ORDER_GROUP INT
)
DECLARE @StartCount INT, @LastCount INT
DECLARE @division VARCHAR(10),
    @Id VARCHAR(10),
    @order VARCHAR(10),
    @date DATETIME,
    @ORDER_GROUP INT


SELECT @StartCount = 1, @ORDER_GROUP = 1
SELECT @LastCount = COUNT(0) FROM @MainTable

WHILE(@StartCount <= @LastCount)
BEGIN
    IF(@StartCount = 1)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @RequiredTable
        (
            division,
            Id ,
            [order] ,
            [date] ,
            ORDER_GROUP
        )
        SELECT division,
        Id,
        [order],
        [date], 
        1
        FROM
        (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY division) AS ROWNUM, * 
        FROM @MainTable) tbl
        WHERE ROWNUM = @StartCount
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT @division = division,
        @Id = Id,
        @order  = [order],
        @date = [date]
        FROM
        (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY division) AS ROWNUM, * 
        FROM @MainTable) tbl
        WHERE ROWNUM = @StartCount

        IF EXISTS(SELECT 0 FROM @RequiredTable WHERE RowId = @StartCount - 1 AND division = @division AND Id = @Id)
        BEGIN
            IF(SUBSTRING(@order,1,5) = 'ORDER')
            BEGIN
                SET @ORDER_GROUP = @ORDER_GROUP + 1
            END
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @ORDER_GROUP = 1
        END

        INSERT INTO @RequiredTable
        (
            division,
            Id ,
            [order] ,
            [date] ,
            ORDER_GROUP
        )
        VALUES (@division,
        @Id,
        @order,
        @date, 
        @ORDER_GROUP)
    END

    SET @StartCount = @StartCount + 1
END

SELECT * FROM @RequiredTable
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perhaps DENSE_RANK was the wrong function to use.  It simply needs to group by division and ID, assigning an incremental order group each time it encounters in the ORDER column text like 'ORDER%'.

I'll run through this later, but thought for sure that it could be done with a CTE rather than a loop.  Who knows, when I run it through, it may be exactly what I'm looking for.

Thanks.

Comment: I have my doubts if it will be possible through a CTE. If you are talking about a recursive CTE then it requires another column, like self primary-foreign key to make it work. Other than that CTE is just a way of reducing clutter in a query and make it look more cleaner. Anyways do let me know if you are able to achieve it through a CTE. It will help me learn as well. :)